# why does newtxmath fail to work with pdflatex and libertine

Tags: libertine, newtx

There seems to be some sort of incompatibility between the `newtxmath` package and `libertine-legacy`; the following code fails to compile:

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
 \begin{document}
 $a = 1$
 \end{document}
```

when compiled through `pdflatex`, as it results in latex trying to find a `Libertine-nu` font which doesn't seem to exist:

```
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Libertine-nu
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation L for Libertine-nu.
/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; nonstopmode; input Libertine-nu
```

I installed the latest version of the package from: http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/libertine-legacy.tds.zip today, and haven't tried this before so don't know if it's a recent breakage or not.

I'd prefer to continue using `pdflatex` because the `microtype` package that doesn't seem to work well with `lualatex` or `xelatex` yet.  Changing the package over to use the `libertineotf` package and compiling with `xelatex` does work.

Comment: Please file a bug report to the author of `newtx`, who is usually very responsive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest version of the newtx package, which comes with its own (stripped down) version of the Libertine font. Unfortunately, there's a 
small packaging error: The `Libertine-nu.tfm` file has the wrong case. Changing

`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newtx/libertine-nu.tfm`

to

`/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/newtx/Libertine-nu.tfm`

should do the trick.

Comment: I would never have thought of that! Running `mktexlsr` (also known as `texhash`) is necessary after having changed the name. Are Libertine-nu and LibertineZI-nu different?

Comment: `LibertineZI-nu` is a semibold italic variant and `Libertine-nu` the default medium variant

Answer (score 4):

It's a very obscure bug indeed. I traced it in the `nxlmia.vf` virtual font file.

If one runs `vftovp $(kpsewhich nxlmia.vf)` from a Bash shell, the output will read

```
(VTITLE )
(FAMILY UNSPECIFIED)
(FACE F MRR)
(CODINGSCHEME FONTSPECIFIC)
(DESIGNSIZE R 10.0)
(COMMENT DESIGNSIZE IS IN POINTS)
(COMMENT OTHER SIZES ARE MULTIPLES OF DESIGNSIZE)
(CHECKSUM O 24175074123)
(SEVENBITSAFEFLAG TRUE)
(FONTDIMEN
   (SLANT R 0.0)
   (SPACE R 0.25)
   (STRETCH R 0.3)
   (SHRINK R 0.1)
   (XHEIGHT R 0.478)
   (QUAD R 1.0)
   (EXTRASPACE R 0.06)
   )
(MAPFONT D 0
   (FONTNAME rfxlr-alt)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 30127131230)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME Libertine-nu)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
(MAPFONT D 2
   (FONTNAME txmia)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 4141071701)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
[...]
```

and the bug shows in the instruction `MAPFONT D1`, where the requested font is the inexistent `Libertine-nu`. All the other virtual fonts that need it call instead `LibertineZI-nu` which exists.

### A temporary fix

Run from a Bash shell

```
cp $(kpsewhich libertine-tfm) Libertine-nu.tfm
vftovp $(kpsewhich nxlmia.vf) > nxlmia.vpl
```

Run

```
vptovf nxlmia.vpl
```

and keep the resulting file `nxlmia.tfm` and `nxlmia.vf` in the same directory as the document you're working on along with `Libertine-nu.tfm`

If you are bold enough you can move the two files to replace those provided by TeX Live (or MiKTeX). When `newtx` will be updated to correct the issue, there will not be anything to do, other than removing the three files.